# Jasper Report Creation failed when executing JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);

Tags: jasper-reports

```
Could not create the report Report design not valid : 
     1. Warning : Element bottom reaches outside band area : y=3 height=1 band-height=0
     2. Warning : Element bottom reaches outside band area : y=0 height=29 band-height=0 Report design not valid
```

I am new to jasper Reports 4.5.1. Problem is that the above message is being displayed when i call the function with follwoing code.

```
 JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, jdbcConnection);
 JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
```

Lots of thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is usually displayed when you have overlapping areas in your template, a field edging out the repeating band for example.
From the details of the error message it looks like you have 2 elements with a non zero height trying to be positioned in bands which have been collapsed to zero height.

I hope this helps.

Comment: When i created another report the error message disappeared but following exception is now coming.  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.createClassVisitor(CompilationUnit.java:791)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:755)
  org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:967)
 org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:546)